# Lock vertex in UV editor

Tags: vertices, faces, uv-image-editor

I need to fit UV map to the texture. To do this, I use proportional editing to move the necessary sections of the UV map. But when moving, vertices/faces that I don’t want to move are moved, how can I block / freeze them from moving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the vertices you don't want to edit and hide them (H), then perform the edit, then unhide all (Alt H).